# How to declare schema for at least one property is not null using JSON Schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jsonschema

```
const personData= {
  name: null,
  email: 'test@gmail.com'
}

const schema = {
  instance: personData,
  schema: {
    type: "object",
    anyOf: [
      { required: ["name", "email"] }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want a schema which will validate the object and from object any of the key value (name or email) where one of them must be not null.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're confused between "undefined" and "null", which are distinctly different. (I've now edited your question in light of your comment on my answer.)

The `required` keyword makes sure that a key is "defined" in the applicable object. The value is irrelevant, and may be `null`.

If you want to define the TYPE of a property, you have to use the `type` keyword.

`anyOf` must be an array of schemas where at least one of them must be true.

You've defined one subschema in the `anyOf`, and as a result, it must be true as a whole, making both items in the `required` array, required.

You want to define multiple schemas under your `anyOf`, where one each schema defines that a property must be of a specific type (`null` is a type).

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["name", "email"],
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: No you didnt get it, ok i will have this two properties but what about if both the properies have null value ?? I want schema which will make sure atleast one of this two properties have value line  { name : 'test' , email : null }

Comment: I'll edit my answer, but essentially you have to define their type.

Comment: Please note, "defined" is not the same as "null", and you asked for "defined". Undefined is different to null explicitly.

Comment: Plz read the question carefully, your answer will be really helpful for me

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect your actual question. I've also edited your question based on your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by placing the 'required' property under the anyof list

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "required": ["name"],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "required": ["email"],
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `required` attribute means you must have a property in data. It may be nullable, though. To exclude `null` values make sure that `anyOf` properties you need are `not` `null`:

```
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "not": {
            "type": "null"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "not": {
            "type": "null"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

---

Full version goes below:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    "email": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "name",
    "email"
  ],
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "not": {
            "type": "null"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "not": {
            "type": "null"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```